# SQL Results to XML File - Using "FOR XML PATH"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, for-xml-path

I have written a SQL query using `FOR XML PATH` and the results return in one line.  If you click on that one line of returned XML, then a new window opens and you can see the data in XML format, perfectly nested as I need.

I then copy that XML data into a flat file, encrypt it and ship to whoever needs it.  So what I want to do is automate the copying and pasting of the xml into a flat file with SSIS or whatever is easiest but I cannot for the life of me figure this out or find another forum post of someone trying this same thing.

So my question is, when you write a SQL query and use `FOR XML PATH` for the output and you get the one line of data in XML format, how do you convert\export that one line of XML data into a file so that it looks like the data (perfectly nested) when you click on the one line?

Comment: What is your input and expected output ?

Comment: Whatever's easiest is up to the eye of the beholder. We use a lot of SQL CLR already, so for us the easiest is using a CLR procedure to write XML to a given file and have controls over whether or not the `<?xml?>` declaration gets generated, what character encoding to use, etc.. Others probably prefer using `bcp.exe -queryout`.

Comment: When I click on the XML link after my query runs, the output looks like below and is exactly how I need it to be in a flat file:

<Detail>
  <Table1>
    <Facility>Facility ABC</Facility>
    <Student>John Doe</Student>
    <User_ID>98363</User_ID>
    <Email>JohnDoe@gmail.com</Email>
    <Department>OTHER</Department>
    <Class>CPR</Class>
    <Status>NA</Status>
    <Type>Classroom</Type>
    <Course>Course ABC</Course>
    <Grade>0</Grade>
    <Start_Date>02-04-2020</Start_Date>
    <Start_Time>08:30 AM</Start_Time>
    <End_Time>09:30 AM</End_Time>
  </Table1>
<Detail>

Comment: Dang, it didn't nest it in the comment like I wanted it to.  I will try to add a print screen.

Comment: I guess it won't allow me to add a print screen file : (

Comment: I will research the following and see if I can figure it out:

CLR procedure to export xml file

Comment: To restate the question: how do I export "well formatted" XML to a file?

Comment: I believe I have this working using the below work around that I got from the even more below URL:

1 - Send data to a RecordSet destination
2 - Use a script task to convert the RecordSet into a DataTable object
3 - Use the DataTable.WriteXML() function to export the XML file

The below URL is what I used to guide me and I used the 2nd option, "Script component destination" instead of the FOR XML clause.

https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-xml-destination/

This worked perfectly for what I needed.  Thanks guys for reading and responding.